# How can I move the cursor to a postion where I want in office word by vb?

Tags: vba, ms-word

> 12345qwesdfasdf22232  & 021930

Like the string above, I want to move the cursor to the position after the character `&` by searching the character in the string. How can I achieve it when I using visual basic to control the word?

```
Option Explicit

Dim WordApp As Word.Application   

Private Sub Command2_Click()
    Set WordApp = New Word.Application

    WordApp.Documents.Open CommonDialog1.FileName     
    WordApp.Visible = True 
    WordApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    ...
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried selecting the string then using Word's Find capability to search an ampersand? That will select the ampersand. Then press right-arrow to move the selection to after the ampersand. Record that in a macro, once you can do it in the UI and that will give you the code to select the ampersand in the selected string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are outputting using `Selection.TypeText`, you can use

```
Selection.MoveStartUntil "&", wdBackward
Selection.MoveLeft 1
```

which will move you backwards until the first occurrence of the ampersand.

You can also do as Cindy Meister mentioned, do a `Selection.Find` similar to...

```
With Selection.Find
    .MatchWildCards = false
    .Text = "&"
    .Execute
End With
```