# How to locate specific string in word document and replace with automatic table of contents with Excel VBA script?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am writing a VBA script in Excel which needs to add a table of contents to a pre-existing word document in a specific location.

I have a word document with the following text somewhere in it: [contents_table_placeholder]

I want to find the text [contents_table_placeholder] and replace it with a word document automatic contents table.

However, I am struggling to get the table of contents to appear anywhere other than at the start of the document. My initial approach was to do a find and replace (replacing [contents_table_placeholder] with an empty string). I thought this would place the cursor in the correct place to then add the contents table but unfortunately this method doesn't work.

```
Sub createContentsPage()

Dim objWord As Word.Application
Dim inputDoc As Word.Document
Dim rngWord As Word.Range

Set objWord = New Word.Application

With objWord
    .Visible = True
    Set inputDoc = .Documents.Open( _
                Filename:="C:\test.docx", _
                ReadOnly:=False)
End With

With inputDoc.Content.Find
    .Text = "[contents_table_placeholder]"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .ExecuteReplace:=wdReplaceOne
End With

With inputDoc
    Set rngWord = .Range(Start:=0, End:=0)

    .TablesOfContents.Add _
        Range:=rngWord, _
        UseFields:=True, _
        UseHeadingStyles:=True, _
        LowerHeadingLevel:=2, _
        UpperHeadingLevel:=1
End With

Set objWord = Nothing
Set inputDoc = Nothing
Set rngWord = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36737670/how-can-i-move-the-cursor-to-a-postion-where-i-want-in-office-word-by-vb

Comment: Also, this may help you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821348.aspx

Comment: Neither of these worked. I still don't understand why but in the end I found a work around solution which was to create the table at the start of the document and then add some lines of code to cut and paste to the correct location.

Comment: Glad to hear that. You should post this workaround as an answer so later people can find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After other attempts failed, I came up with the following work-around solution which involves creating the table of contents at the top of the document first and then cutting and pasting into the desired location.

```
Sub createContentsPage()

Dim objWord As Word.Application
Dim inputDoc As Word.Document
Dim rngWord As Word.Range

Set objWord = New Word.Application

With objWord
    .Visible = True
    Set inputDoc = .Documents.Open( _
            Filename:="C:\test.docx", _
            ReadOnly:=False)
End With

'Create table of contents at top of document
With inputDoc
    Set rngWord = .Range(Start:=0, End:=0)      
    .TablesOfContents.Add _
    Range:=rngWord, _
    UseFields:=True, _
    UseHeadingStyles:=True, _
    LowerHeadingLevel:=2, _
    UpperHeadingLevel:=1
End With

'Scroll to top of document
objWord.Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

'Select contents table
objWord.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend

'Cut contents table
objWord.Selection.Cut

'Find placeholder and delete (cursor will remain at place holder)
With inputDoc.Content.Find
    .Text = "[contents_table_placeholder]"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .ExecuteReplace:=wdReplaceOne
End With

'Insert new line
objWord.Selection.TypeParagraph

'Paste contents table
objWord.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)

inputDoc.Save
inputDoc.Close

Set objWord = Nothing
Set inputDoc = Nothing
Set rngWord = Nothing

End Sub
```